# Difference between "github-pages" and "jekyll" gem?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

What are the main differences between the two gems `jekyll` and `github-pages`?

And why does [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/) recommend using `github-page` with Pages?

Comment: Probably because they have more control of `github-pages`.  Note that "Why" in your title is a totally separate question than "What are the differences".  Neither are a easy to answer in a Q&A style, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `github-pages` gem will load [all dependencies](https://pages.github.com/versions/) needed to run Jekyll exactly like on GitHub Pages.

`jekyll` gem is just Jekyll.